# C++ Draw text on bitmap image without other library

Tags: c++, bitmap, bmp, bitmapimage

I am writing a class in C++14 that gives the ability to read, write and edit bmp images. I must not use any third party library and do it all alone. I manage to read, write and draw shapes on the image, but I couldn't find a way to draw text without a library. Any suggestions?

Comment: You could setup an array with bitmaps for characters. Then writing the text is looking up the bitmap for each character, copying the bitmap of that character into the target bitmap, and move the insertion position with the resp. width of the character bitmap. Thereby, set bits can be interpreted to set a pixel of a pre-configured color where a non-set bit can be either interpreted to set another pre-configured color (text with background color) or do nothing (text with transparent background).

Comment: Look at an existing library and copy its approach?

Comment: But only copy the algorithm, not the code (that's copyright infringement). Preferably use someone else to look at other libraries, write down the algorithm, and then you implement it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Well, [stb_truetype](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_truetype.h) is public domain, so copying the code is legal. Although I suspect OP might have some trouble explaining all the bits inside.

Comment: "do it all alone" a.k.a. asking how to do it on Stack Overflow? ;-)